# SQL engine execution plan of HAVING vs (subquery) WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

When executed, is there any difference at between the following two sql queries:

```
SELECT name, count(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY name HAVING count(*) > 1
```

And:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT name, count(*) cnt FROM mytable GROUP BY name) x where cnt > 1
```

In other words, is having more a "convenience" clause to simplify having to do subselect, or does the query engine fundamentally performance different when a having statement is used vs the second approach? Currently in mysql:

[image]

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf-8;
```

Comment: Very broad question especially if we don't have the create table statement.. And also without knowing MySQL version

Comment: @RaymondNijland updated with table now.

Comment: @RaymondNijland anyways, it sounds based on your answer that the two do differ, and its execution is based on the particular engine?

Comment: *"its execution is based on the particular engine?"* Well MySQL 8 has a much beter optimizer then MySQL 5.7 had. "it sounds based on your answer that the two do differ" well in this case i think the execution speeds will be more or less equal, while some optimizer engines might be able to optimize the inner sql query variant sightly  better because the inner sql resultset is more "limited" and execute it sightly faster.

Comment: Simple rule (in MySQL):  Avoid subqueries when the alternative is not any messier.  MySQL is years (decades?) behind other vendors in subquery optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost any other database, the two would be equivalent.  For conciseness, `HAVING` is usually a better choice.

At least historically, MySQL materialized subqueries.  So, this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT name, count(*) as cnt
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY name
     ) x 
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

suggests that it is going to write out the derived table, and then re-scan it for the final `WHERE`.    However, this makes little difference to performance because the `GROUP BY` is already reading and writing the data.

So, these queries are probably quite similar in performance on MySQL.  And, they would have the same execution plan on almost any other database.  The `HAVING` clause results in the simpler query.

Comment: Or it may have materialized it, then "auto-created" an index on cnt.  In your example, `INDEX(name)` is necessary to avoid yet another temp table.